# In Ant, how can I test if a property ends with a given value?

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

In Ant, how can I test if a property ends with a given value?

For example

```
 <property name="destdir" 
     value="D:\FeiLong Soft\Essential\Development\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans" />
```

how can I test if `${destdir}` ends with `"spring-beans"`?

**additional：**

In my ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar, without 'endswith' task~~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Matteo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13649958/368630), Ant-Contrib contains a lot of nice stuff, and I use it heavily.

However, in this case can simply use the `<basename>` task:

```
<basename property="basedir.name" file="${destdir}"/>
<condition property="ends.with.spring-beans">
   <equals arg1="spring-beans" arg2="${basedir.name}"/>
<condition>
```

The property `${ends.with.spring-beans}` will contain `true` if `${destdir}` ends with `string-beans` and `false` otherwise. You could use it in the `if` or `unless` parameter of the `<target>` task.

Comment: This works for testing if the last component of a path equals "spring-beans". It will not work to test if a property strictly ends with that substring.

Answer (score 4):

You can test if ${destdir} ends with "spring-beans" like this (assuming you have ant-contrib, and are using Ant 1.7 or later).

```
<property name="destdir" value="something\spring-beans" />
<condition property="destDirHasBeans">
  <matches pattern=".*spring-beans$" string="${destdir}" /> 
</condition>
<if>
  <equals arg1="destDirHasBeans" arg2="true" />
  <then>
      $destdir ends with spring-beans ...
  </then>
  <else> ...
  </else>
</if>
```

The '$' in the regex pattern `".*spring-beans$"` is an anchor to match at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript power can be used for string manipulation in the ANT:

```
<script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[

        // getting the value for property sshexec.outputproperty1
        str = project.getProperty("sshexec.outputproperty1");

        // get the tail , after the separator ":"
       str = str.substring(str.indexOf(":")+1,str.length() ).trim();

        // store the result in a new property
        project.setProperty("res",str);


    ]]> </script>
<echo message="Responce ${res}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [EndWith](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/more_conditions.html) condition from [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net)

```
<endswith string="${destdir}" with="spring-beans"/>
```

For example

```
<if>
    <endswith string="${destdir}" with="spring-beans"/>
    <then>
        <!-- do something -->
    </then>
</if>
```

**Edit**

`<endswith>` is part of the Ant-Contrib package that has to be installed and enabled with

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>
```

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/forums/forum/113701/topic/3635945?message=8209729  I have the same questions and this

Comment: Does not work! got error message "if doesn't support the nested "endswith" element."

Comment: @SJunejo did you install and enable ant-contrib? Which version of ants contrib are you using?

Comment: I am using ant-contrib1.0b3 in my project. I have solved it by writing my own endswith as javascript and called but offcourse not inside 'if' :(

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670197/use-ant-contrib-how-to-use-endswith